# Window manager. Internal content of X windows in separate window?

Tags: qt4, xlib, window-managers, x11, qt4.7

I am writing my own Window Manager using Xlib and Qt 4.7. So in my application I catch all events from XServer.

The problem is next. When I show window on "MapRequest" event, sometimes its internal content shows in separate window. Most often I face with this problem in browsers (like Firefox and Google Chrome) after open new webpage, sometimes in Qt Creator and Dolphin after open dialog window, also in media players. What could be a reason of that? What I missed?

Any advices are welcome.

Here is MapRequest handler.

```
bool Manager::mapRequestHandler(XEvent* pEvent)
{
    Window lWindow = pEvent->xmaprequest.window;

    QMWindowWidget* lWidget = findWidget(lWindow);
    if (!lWidget)
    {
        lWidget = (QMWindowWidget*)QWidget::find(lWindow);
    }

    if (lWidget)
    {
        XMapWindow(QX11Info::display(), lWindow);
        lWidget->show();
        XRaiseWindow(QX11Info::display(), lWidget->winId());
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"CREATING WINDOW IN MAP_REQUEST...";
        createClientWindow(lWindow); //this function calls only here.
        qDebug()<<"WINDOW CREATED";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is createClientWindow() function.

```
void Manager::createClientWindow(Qt::HANDLE pWinID)
{
    XWindowAttributes lWinAttr;
    if(!XGetWindowAttributes(QX11Info::display(), pWinID, &lWinAttr))
    {
        return;
    }
    if(lWinAttr.override_redirect)
    {
        return;
    }

    QStringList lWindowType = getWindowType(pWinID);
    if(lWindowType[0] == "Desktop")
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(lWindowType[0] == "Splash"       || lWindowType[0] == "Dock" ||
            lWindowType[0] == "KDE_override" || lWindowType[0] == "Popup_menu")
    {
        XMapWindow(QX11Info::display(), pWinID);
        XRaiseWindow(QX11Info::display(), pWinID);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        QMWindowWidget *lWindowWidget = new QMWindowWidget(pWinID, lWinAttr);
        connect(lWindowWidget, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), this, SLOT(slotWidgetDestroyed(QObject*)));
        mListWindows.append(lWindowWidget);
    }
}
```

Constructor of QMWindowWidget.

```
mClientAttr = pWinAttr;
mWmHints = XGetWMHints(QX11Info::display(), pWindow);

XGrabServer(QX11Info::display());

XTextProperty lTitle;
XGetWMName(QX11Info::display(), pWindow, &lTitle);
this->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8((const char*)lTitle.value));
qDebug()<<pWindow<<(const char*)lTitle.value;

int widgetX = pWinAttr.x - 3;
int widgetY = pWinAttr.y - 33;
if (widgetX < 0)
{
    widgetX = 0;
}
if (widgetY < 0)
{
    widgetY = 0;
}
XAddToSaveSet(QX11Info::display(), pWindow);
XSetWindowBorderWidth(QX11Info::display(), pWindow, 0);
XResizeWindow(QX11Info::display(), pWindow, pWinAttr.width, pWinAttr.height);
this->setGeometry(widgetX, widgetY, pWinAttr.width + 6, pWinAttr.height + 33);

XSelectInput(QX11Info::display(),this->winId(),
             KeyReleaseMask | KeyPressMask |
             ButtonMotionMask|
             ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask |
             FocusChangeMask |
             ExposureMask |
             StructureNotifyMask |
             SubstructureNotifyMask |
             SubstructureRedirectMask);

XReparentWindow(QX11Info::display(), pWindow, this->winId(), 3, 30);

XSelectInput(QX11Info::display(), pWindow,
             ColormapChangeMask |
             PropertyChangeMask |
             StructureNotifyMask);

this->show();
XMapWindow(QX11Info::display(), pWindow);
XRaiseWindow(QX11Info::display(), this->winId());
XSetInputFocus(QX11Info::display(), pWindow, RevertToParent, CurrentTime);

XUngrabServer(QX11Info::display());
XSync(QX11Info::display(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to show ONLY your top-level windows, and only when they are supposed to be shown. I had the same issue and I discovered I was showing the client window in more places then MapRequest event handler! So check your code, maybe you're handling another event that shows a window without explicit request!

If you need any further help, please post all your event handlers, then comment my answer, I will edit it and try to bring you help.

Comment: I have already found cause of issue. I had one odd flag in event mask for clients (SubstructureRedirectMask). This flag needed only for root window and my own windows that I create.

But in one case it still doesn't work. When I have a video on webpage (for example on YouTube) and try expand it to fullscreen, video appears in separate window. I am sure that I'm not create borders in another places except MapRequest. Maybe my check for "top-level window" is not correct?

Comment: Please don't add your code as separate answers, edit your question instead.

Comment: Then, when you see a flash object on a web page, it is an X Window. When you click on the full-screen button, the window should be reparented as a top-level window and resized. Are you forgetting to use the override_redirect flag in your ReparentNotify handler?

Comment: I don't have ReparentNotify handler at all. But I have debug output of this event and I don't receive ReparentNotify from window with video, only MapRequest. And debug output in MapRequest says that it is "top-level" not "override_redirect" window. And it has NORMAL type. I wonder how to know that this window should not has borders.
What else properties can influence on that?